# AFNetworking send array in JSON parameters of GET request

Tags: objective-c, iphone, json, afnetworking, afnetworking-2

I am sending array as a parameter in AFNetworking GET Request.

My code is as follows:

```
- (void)getProductSearchResult:(NSString *)locale andSearchDict:(NSDictionary *)dictSearch{

    NSString *strURL = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/search?%@",BASEURL,locale,APIFORMAT];

    AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    manager.requestSerializer = [AFJSONRequestSerializer serializer];
    [manager GET:strURL parameters:dictSearch success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

        NSDictionary *jsonDict = (NSDictionary *)responseObject;

        if ([jsonDict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] || [jsonDict isKindOfClass:[NSMutableDictionary class]]) {
            if (self.delegate  && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(API_ProductSearch_didSuccess:)]) {
                [self.delegate API_ProductSearch_didSuccess:jsonDict];
            }
        }
    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        if (self.delegate && [self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(api_ProductSearch_didFailWithError:)]) {
            [self.delegate api_ProductSearch_didFailWithError:[NSError description]];
        }
    }];
}
```

The dictionary which I pass as parameter is as follows:

```
{
    "brand_filter" =     (
        1
    );
    "category_filter" =     (
        438
    );
    "max_price" = "47.37188";
    "min_price" = "1.95";
    "price_currency" = USD;
    "supplier_filter" =     (
        "Aakron Line"
    );
}
```

URL which created is shown like

```
http://demo.aakronline.ca/app_dev.php/api/v1/en_us/search?_format=json&brand_filter[]=1&category_filter[]=438&max_price=48.04479&min_price=2.622917&price_currency=USD&supplier_filter[]=Aakron%20Line
```

The problem area in URL is array is not passed in proper format i.e.

```
brand_filter[]=1&category_filter[]=438 instead of brand_filter=[1]&category_filter=[438]
```

Can anyone tell me how to solve this mistake?

But I am not getting the successful response.

Comment: first of all check in Postman.. so verify that Url and perameters are correct,  LInk : https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en

Comment: I have checked in postman, It is working but problme is in URL where array is passed in such format, brand_filter[]=1&category_filter[]=438. Which is not correct format.

Comment: i think create one Dictionary and pass it instead of array. try ionce

Comment: try to use in this formate
http://demo.aakronline.ca//app_dev.php/api/v1/en_us/search?_format=json&brand_filter=["22","34"]

Answer (score 0):

In afnetworking 3.0, instead of `AFHTTPRequestOperationManager` use `AFHTTPSessionManager`

```
NSString *strUrl = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@/search?%@",BASEURL,locale,APIFORMAT];
AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [[AFHTTPSessionManager alloc] init];
manager.responseSerializer = [AFJSONResponseSerializer serializer];

[manager GET:strUrl parameters:nil progress:nil success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {
    NSLog(@"value: %@",responseObject);

 //other code as it is

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {

    NSLog(@"Error: %@",error);
}];
```